# Can "email" be a shortened form of "email address"?

Tags: word-usage, email

Can I use the word "email" to mean "email address"?

For example:

- *Please tell me your **email**.*
- *You can use your **email** as an ID.*

Dictionaries such as [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e-mail) don’t list this definition.

Comment: Email (eMail) is the short form of electronic mail.  Ideally, you could use mail ID/ email ID which is in practice.

Comment: I've certainly heard and used it, including yesterday while collecting contact information: "What's your email?"

Comment: Google claims thousands of hits for the quoted search string ["**login using email or username**"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02O47HkGjuRAZmzCVKIKHOMaqP-Og%3A1602155304893&ei=KPN-X8yCNsOM8gLW0Y2YCg&q=%22login+using+email+or+username%22&oq=%22login+using+email+or+username%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjoECAAQRzoICAAQCBAHEB46BggAEA0QHlCUH1iqL2DENmgAcAJ4AIAB0wGIAY8FkgEFNS4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjMtsrO7aTsAhVDhlwKHdZoA6MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5), a context that *forces* the interpretation *"email" = email **address***.

Comment: @RamPillai this is literally the first time in my entire life that I see the words "email ID" together.

Comment: It's somewhat informal, but commonly used and well-understood.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, You should be correct, but it is also true that we in India hear it a lot, as common as https://businessemail.rediff.com/faq/email/91.html. I am happy being corrected. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/60701) (paywalled) **does** have "email" as available to mean "email address".

> A system for sending textual messages (with or without attached files) to one or more recipients via a computer network (esp. the internet); a message or messages sent using this system. Also: an email address.

Even so, it's in common use, even if Merriam-Webster hasn't caught up yet — although OED updated its entry in 2011, so it's not exactly a cutting-edge use of language.